# CF - QoQ vs Query

Tags: coldfusion, qoq

I've got a notion that calling a query of queries is faster than a query from database, because the slowdown is in the communication between cf and the db. Is this true.

Does that mean that a QoQ within a loop is acceptable, whereas a query within a loop is not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Full DBMS are highly optimised for processing [appropriately-written] queries, and on a modern network the overhead is not going to be huge.

QoQ are performed using an embedded database, which may or not be well optimised, depending on the type of query being performed.

So, if the database is on a different machine, across a slow network, the QoQ might be less slow in some situations. If you're hitting the database at all, you ideally want to get everything processed appropriately there, in one request, and avoid both round-trips and re-processing in a loop.

Of course, a big benefit of QoQ is that you can use it to process data that doesn't come from a database - such as the results of cfdirectory or a CSV file that has been converted to a query.

ColdFusion performs QoQ by manually parsing the SQL and then looping through the recordset. This makes it efficient for simple operations, such as a two-table join with matching keys, but less efficient for complex combinations (where joining uses multiple columns and/or is not a straight a=b comparison). ([Brief info here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7fb8).)

Railo uses [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). H2 claims to be fast, and their website offers some [speed comparisons](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html) that suggest it is faster than Derby and MySQL - but of course it would be best to look for independent third-party tests, not to mention that these tests are not guarantees of QoQ performance (which I suspect wont have indexes, for example).

In general: **don't make any hard decision without first doing performance testing** to determine that you actually need to improve performance, and to be able to objectively determine which method is actually faster.

Comment: Derby isn't used in ACF's QoQ features. Derby is included with it for having easy access to a low-overhead database. ACF's QoQ uses something more like manual SQL parsing and looping to change recordsets.

Comment: Eww. :/  Is there any further info on that you can point at, so I can update the answer accordingly?

Comment: I don't have any external resources, aside from conversations I've had with Adobe personnel and years of experience :P

Comment: Shame. I've updated that part anyway. Probably improve it more later, but have to go now.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the capabilities of your Coldfusion machine as compared to your database server, and the problem that you're trying to solve.

QofQ will generally be very fast for small datasets because it all happens in your server memory. If you try to use QofQ on a large dataset though, your server will start to have problems due to the overhead involved with keeping and processing that data in memory.

Database queries will generally outperform QofQ on large datasets because *that's what they are designed for*. Databases are good at processing large amounts of data very fast. Use them for that.

If you're considering retrieving a large result set from the database and parsing it with QofQ, that is probably the wrong way to do it. Make the database reduce the results for you instead. If you're asking the database server for this information frequently, then cache it on your server.

Keep in mind that this is all subjective and will depend a lot on your particular problem, load, database and server capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that using a q OF q can be MUCH faster than pulling DB's from a query.

For example, I religiously use QoQ on sales reports.   I have a sales report that would be pulled for a 1st quarter date range, that may show Sales figures by sales agent, and it may also show sales figures by product sold.

In my DB, the same tables/fields would be used for both sections that would appear on the same report.

I query the main table for my data based off the date range, and then I query those results to build each section of my report.

I found this this method was faster on both servers with the DB local and remote.

Comment: Have you had a DBA look at your database and queries? A quarterly sales report is likely to have a lot of data, and be something that a DBMS can be optimised for.

Comment: I have had similar results. Sometimes databases are slow for any number of reasons. Sometimes you want to join or union your queries in CF. Sometimes QoQ is way faster. Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 3):

Times to use QofQ

- When you have two datasources and for various reasons you can use linked servers
- When the data comes in via WDDX or JSON and you have to do a join
- When it is practical to store data in a cached query and do QofQ against the cached query
- When you have to join the result of a directoryList() against a data base

Times to not use QofQ

- When you can load the data into a struct instead
- When doing doing a massive number of iterations
- When the one of source data sets is very large
- When you need to do a left, right, or outer join

For more details see

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html

This is for CF 9 but QofQ has been about the same since CF 6

Comment: ah yes, I did neglect to mention that my Q is using a join, that does play a big role

Comment: You can do outer joins if you try hard enough.  Think union query, ValueList, and not in ().

Answer (score 0):

Dude!  Just used cachedwithin.